# VBA Removed filtered row while keeping header

Tags: vba, filter, delete-row

I managed to get the filter row using the following.

```
Sub FilterRows()
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=" = "
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```

But when I tried to use this to remove the filtered row, it ends up delete my entire data except my header.

```
Public Sub test()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

How can I just removed the filtered row while keeping my data and header?

Answer (score 1):

Change the range in the brackets to fit your range and try:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & Lastrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Can I know how do I determine the range "$A$1:$A$"?

Comment: @which is the first & last cell of your table?

Comment: It's Column A to N,  I have 3 rows of filtered need to remove. 
Header is A1 to N1
Do I put like this; 
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$N" & Lastrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: yes the above is the correct but before you must declare & calculate Lastrow of column N.

Declare:
Dim Lastrow  as long

Calculation:
Lastrow =Sheet1 .Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Change the Sheet if needed

Comment: Also you forgot something in the brackets.use  ActiveSheet.Range("$A1:$N" & Lastrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _ (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ill give it a try once I go back. Great day ahead!

Comment: When I use the following code, it shows, "Compile error: invalid character" ;
"ActiveSheet.Range("$A1:$N" & Lastrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _ (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete 
" Even though I declare the last row; 
Dim Lastrow As Long

    Last = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Check Lastrow value & check the line of the error.maybe there as an extra character.